# Find out which button user clicked to close Twwsearchdialog

Tags: delphi-7

I am building a project in which I use Infopowers and 1stClass controls.
Now in one of my forms i use a TwwSearchDialog in order to let the user locate a specific record. However, i want to know with which button did the user closed the dialog.
That is because if he clicked the 'Cancel' button i need to trigger different code than if he had clicked the 'OK' button.

The TwwSearchDialog control has an "OnCloseDialog" event in which the sender is of TwwLookUpDlg which does not have any 'Canceled' Boolean parameter. (Same situation with TwwSearchDialog itself). Thus you can not ask whether the dialog was canceled or not.

I tried to go around by querying the 'Execute' parameter in the 'OnCloseDialog' event which, even though Boolean, does not return nothing.

```
procedure MyForm.wwSearchDialog1CloseDialog(Dialog:TwwLookupDlg);
begin
   if not wwSearchDialog1.Execute then
      begin
         bla bla bla bla
      end;
end;
```

Instead it produces a serious flaw by making infeasible to close the dialog (either with cancel or ok) except if you terminate the project violently.

Could you please provide me a way to check with which button did the user close the dialog ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Dialog' parameter of the OnCloseDialog event of the TwwSearchDialog has an attribute called: 'ModalResult'.
Now if the SearchDialog is closed by pressing the 'Cancel' button, then Dialog.ModalResult = mrCancel. 
If the SearchDialog is closed by pressing the 'OK' button, then Dialog.ModalResult = mrOK.

So in the 'OnCloseDialog' Event i can query whether Dialog.ModalResult is equal to mrOk or mrCancel and add, accordingly, the proper code.